# Is it "normal" to require the `ConfigurationAttribute`s in an AuthenticationFilter in Spring Security?

Tags: java, spring, spring-security

Or does it identify a design problem ?

To decide whether I should continue the filter chain in a custom `AuthenticationFilter` of mine I need to check whether the `Authentication` is an `AnonymousAuthenticationToken` **and** whether the current matched URL has an `access="permitAll"` attribute (which is usually handled by the `FilterSecurityInterceptor`).

So

```
<!-- chain should continue past authentication regardless of authentication type (anonymous/actual) -->
<security:intercept-url pattern="/pages/public/public.html" access="permitAll"/>

<!-- chain should continue only on non-anonymous authentication -->
<security:intercept-url pattern="/pages/authenticated/stuff.html" access="isAuthenticated()"/>
```

In other words I need a way to identify URL paths on which I should skip authentication, but still have an anonymous token so the security interceptor works as usual.

I'm using Spring Security 3.0.1, so separate filter chains for different URL paths is not currently an option.

Answer (score 1):

Well you are mixing authentication and authorization, so it certainly is a smell. What is the problem with doing `access="IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY"`?